# Change detail disclosure indicator image on touch

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

Is it possible to change the `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton` image on touch?

I would like to have my rows in the tableView to have an empty circle in place of the detail disclosure button. When I tap this empty circle button, I would like to change the image of the empty circle with another image containing a checkmark. Then after a delay of about half a second I would like to perform an action with the `-accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath`.

How can I do this?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella I am already able to customize the button so that it has the empty circle. I followed this [link](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/71147-change-disclosure-button.html)

Comment: What should happen if the user taps something else during that “delay of about half a second”?

Comment: @robmayoff nothing really. I thought of the delay just to have some time for the user to recognize the change in the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first you'd have to set the accessoryView of your cell to be a custom UIView, probably a UIButton...

```
UIImage *uncheckedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Unchecked.png"];
UIImage *checkedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Checked.png"];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(44.0, 44.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(tapButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setImage:uncheckedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:checkedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
cell.accessoryView = button;
```

In your tapButton: method you want to apply the necessary changes to the image and perform the accessoryButtonTappedAtIndexPath. I would just avoid the delay or you could use a dispatch timer...

```
- (void)tapButton:(UIButton *)button {
  [button setSelected:!button.selected];
  UITableViewCell *cell = [button superview];
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
  [self tableView:tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:indexPath];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment, you are already creating your own button and setting it as the cell's `accessoryView`.

When you create the button, set its image for the selected state to your checkmark image:

```
[button setImage:checkmarkImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

When the button is tapped, set its state to selected so it will show the checkmark:

```
- (IBAction)buttonWasTapped:(id)sender event:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIButton *button = sender;
    button.selected = YES;
```

Then, disable user interactions so the user can't do anything else during the delay:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

Get the index path for the cell containing the touched button:

```
    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:button] anyObject];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:
        [touch locationInView:tableView]];
```

Finally, schedule a block to run after the delay.  In the block, re-enable user interactions and send yourself a message including the index path:

```
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(),
    ^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
        [self accessoryButtonTappedForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    });
}
```

Comment: Good solution. I would avoid the touch logic since you know the superview of the button is the cell. Then you can just called [tableView indexPathForCell:cell] to get the index path.

Comment: @BenM You should not rely on the button being a direct subview of the cell.  That is an implementation detail that is not part of the public API.  There are a number of ways to get from the button to the cell that only use public APIs.  Using `indexPathForRowAtPoint:` is a short, simple way.